# C++ arithmetic operator overloading—automatic widening?

Tags: c++, templates, generics, math, operator-overloading

I have a `Vector` class which represents a 2D vector. It is templated to allow any numerical type to be used for the *x* and *y* components. As an example, one of the arithmetic operators I overload is `*` for multiplying a vector with a scalar:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
inline const Vector<T> operator*(const Vector<T>& vector, U scalar) {
    return Vector<T>(vector.x * scalar, vector.y * scalar);
}
```

*(I also have a function with the parameters in the opposite order to allow `scalar * Vector` in addition to `Vector * scalar`).*

As you can see, I use `<T, U>` instead of simply `<T>` so that the scalar doesn't have to be the same type as the Vector. When I *didn't* do this, surprisingly `Vector<double> * int` wouldn't compile (I thought the int would automatically widen).

In any case, I don't simply want to return a `Vector<T>`. I want to mimic the built-in types and return whichever has higher precision, `T` or `U`. So for example, `Vector<int> * double => Vector<double>` while `Vector<double> * short => Vector<double>`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two solutions to this. In Pre C++11 you can write a template like:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
struct WhatWillItBe {
  typedef T result_t;
};

template <typename T>
struct WhatWillItBe<T, double> {
  typedef double result_t;
};

// ... lots more
```

etc. and write *a lot* of specialisations, then you can use that to look up the return type, e.g.:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
inline const Vector<typename WhatWillItBe<T,U>::result_t> operator*(const Vector<T>& vector, U scalar) {
    return Vector<typename WhatWillItBe<T,U>::result_t>(vector.x * scalar, vector.y * scalar);
}
```

---

Alternatively C++11 makes this straightforward, you can write `auto` for the return type and use `->` to specify the return type after the rest of the function:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
inline auto operator*(const Vector<T>& vector, U scalar) -> Vector<decltype(vector.x*scalar)> {
    return Vector<decltype(vector.x*scalar)>(vector.x * scalar, vector.y * scalar);
}
```

Which allows you to use `decltype` for the return type of a function, setting it based on what would happen for promotion naturally with `vector.x * scalar`.

Comment: Awesome, wish I could upvote more than once. I keep seeing good applications of the `->` return type syntax all the time.

Comment: Noting, of course, that in C++11 your return type _shouldn't_ be const, as it inhibits move semantics.

Comment: Does clang++ 3.0 support this?

Comment: @Mk12 - looks like it does according to http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html ("New function declarator syntax")

Comment: You're right, your last example compiles when I use `clang++ -std=c++0x` :).

Comment: @ildjarn: Could you expand on why this is (or give a link)? I just finished reading in Effective C++ how the return type *should* be `const`…

Comment: @Mk12 - move constructor/assignment can't take a `const` "thing" by definition - it's going to mutate (and "destroy") the object.

Comment: @awoodland: What exactly is a move constructor? I've never heard that term before. Is it specific to C++11?

Comment: @Mk12 : Effective C++ was written well before C++11; if there's ever a new edition, that recommendation will surely be removed.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `common_type` or `decltype` to cook up something that gives you the resulting type; and then you have to create the actual vector:

```
template <typename A, typename B>
std::vector<typename std::common_type<A, B>::type>
operator*(std::vector<A> const & v, B const & x)
{
    std::vector<typename std::common_type<A, B>::type> res;
    res.reserve(v.size());
    for (A a : v) res.push_back(a * x);
    return res;
}
```

Using `decltype`, you can get at the result type via:

```
decltype(std::declval<A>() * std::declval<B>())
```

For both `std::common_type` and `std::declval` you need to `#include <type_traits>`.

With delayed return types (`auto` and `->`) you can use `decltype` directly on the function arguments, but using `std::declval` feels a bit more hygienic, since it doesn't require you to furnish an actual instance of your type (and thus it is applicable even in situations where this isn't possible).

Comment: I'd not see common_type before! That's rather handy.

Comment: `declval` also looks handy, +1

Comment: Just by the way, I was talking about my own math Vector class, not std::vector, but this is still a great answer. Unfortunately I get an error when `#include`ing `<type_traits>`, so I guess this won't work for me.

Comment: It should be noted that this answer requires C++11; if the OP is restricted to C++03 there isn't much of help here.

Comment: @Mk12: Those traits are only part of C++11, so add `-std=c++0x` in GCC, or use MSVS 10 and above.

Comment: Good old C++, 4 ways to do the same thing… I like the `common_type` solution best, but it is unavailable for me. This answer is equally deserving of being accepted answer, though.